# ¿Como puedo pasar información de un componente Formulario a otro para que renderice contenido dinamico almacenado en un array de objetos en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formularios, react-hooks

Estoy haciendo un pequeño ejercicio donde se simula una enciclopedia de perros. Hay un archivo Data.js que contiene toda la información (nombre, origen, foto, frase...). Tengo un componente Form.jsx que renderiza un desplegable para seleccionar el perro. Este componente despliega sus opciones a través del método .map.
Por otro lado existe otro componente llamado DogCard que debería renderizar toda la información una vez que el se haya seleccionado el perro en el componente  Form.
Entiendo que tengo que pasar props pero no tengo muy claro como hacerlo, he intentado hacer .find pero no me ha salido bien tampoco.

Este es el componente Form:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { dogs } from '../components/Data';
import '../stylesheets/Form.css';

function Form ({onDogChange}) {

  const [selectedDog, setSelectedDog] = useState('Carlino')

  const handleChange = e => {
    setSelectedDog(e.target.value)
    onDogChange(selectedDog)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <label className="choose" htmlFor='dogs'>Elige tu perro:
      <select value={selectedDog} onChange={handleChange}>
        {dogs.map((dog) => (
          <option
            className="option" 
            key={dog.nombre} 
          >
            {dog.nombre}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
      </label>
      <p>Your favorite dog: {selectedDog}</p>
    </>
  )
}

export default Form;
```

y este el DogCard que tiene codigo en bruto para ver como renderiza:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Form from './Form';
import { dogs } from '../components/Data';

function DogCard() {


  return (
    <>
      <Form />
      <div className="container">
        <img 
          className="fotodog"
          src={`../../public/imagenes/${dogs[0].imagen}.jpg`}
          alt='texto'
          />
        <div className="text-container">
          <p className="dogname">{dogs[0].nombre}</p>
          <p className="origen">{dogs[0].origen}</p>
          <p className="frase">{dogs[0].frase}</p>
          <p className="trivia">{dogs[0].trivia}</p>  
        </div> 
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default DogCard
```

Y este sería un ejemplo de como tengo los datos almacenados:

```
export const dogs = [{
  id: 1,
  nombre: 'Carlino',
  imagen: 'carlino',
  alttext: 'Foto de Carlino',
  origen: 'China',
  frase: 'Más cerdito que perrito',
  trivia: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'
},
{
  id: 2,
  nombre: 'Galgo',
  imagen: 'galgo',
  alttext: 'Foto de Galgo',
  orgien: 'España',
  frase: 'Si me escapo no me vas a pillar',
  trivia: 'Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident'
},
{
  id: 3,
  nombre: 'Husky',
  imagen: 'husky',
  alttext: 'Foto de Husky',
  orgien: 'Rusia',
  frase: '¡Qué calor hace aquí!',
  trivia: 'Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt'
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: estas usando `react route` para cambiar de un componente a otro?

Comment: No, solo react. La idea era hacer un ejercicio "sencillo" para afianzar conceptos básicos.

Answer (score 0):

Primero tienes que entender como se pasas las propiedades de tu componente DogCard

```
<CardDog dog={dogs[index]}/>
```

Aqui tu componente pasando el objeto perro completo

```
function DogCard(props) {
  const { dog } = props; // tus props son un objeto y tiene la key dog
  const { nombre, imagen, origen, frase, trivia } = dog;

  return (
    <>
      <Form />
      <div className="container">
        <img 
          className="fotodog"
          src={`../../public/imagenes/${imagen}.jpg`}
          alt='texto'
          />
        <div className="text-container">
          <p className="dogname">{nombre}</p>
          <p className="origen">{origen}</p>
          <p className="frase">{frase}</p>
          <p className="trivia">{trivia}</p>  
        </div> 
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Ahora puede enviar prop por prop

```
function DogCard(props) {
  const { nombre, imagen, origen, frase, trivia} = props; // tus props son un objeto y tienen todas las propiedades de un perro

  return (
    <>
      <Form />
      <div className="container">
        <img 
          className="fotodog"
          src={`../../public/imagenes/${imagen}.jpg`}
          alt='texto'
          />
        <div className="text-container">
          <p className="dogname">{nombre}</p>
          <p className="origen">{origen}</p>
          <p className="frase">{frase}</p>
          <p className="trivia">{trivia}</p>  
        </div> 
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Asi se implementaria

```
<CardDog nombre="Juancho" origen="Inglaterra" frase="Woof" triva="Soy color?" imagen="img33323232"/>
```